# Trouble playing with indexed propertes via new RTTI [D2010]

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, rtti

```
  ShowMessage(TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TStringList)
    .GetProperty('Strings').ToString);
```

Above code fails as .GetProperty returns nil on properties like "Strings", "Objects", "Values" (ones with indexers). I assume this is a known limitation and the question is if there's any way to access those indexed properties (preferably without falling back to the old RTTI utils).

Comment: You have a memory leak because you create a TStringList instance but never free it. ClassInfo is a class function; you can call it directly on the class without creating an instance first. Better yet, since you already know exactly which type's RTTI you want, call the other overload that takes a class reference: `GetType(TStringList)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexed properties don't have RTTI, but the underlying fields do.  So you can access TStringList.FList directly through RTTI.  Be careful, though, as this involves raw pointers, and make sure you don't go beyond the Count property.  You can do similar things with other classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are gaps in the RTTI. Indexed properties are one.

But when you don't get the property name, why you try to access them? ;-) When you know there is such a property you can try a cast instead.

You don't get RTTI for method parameters of the typ

`procedure MyProc(const AParam: array of AType)`

also.

Anybody knowing more elements were we can't get RTTI?